# Why is DispatchQueue.main.async not working in Swift app?

Tags: swift, xcode, asynchronous

I'm struggling with asynchronous code in Swift. I have to disable 2 buttons if there is no internet connection. I have 2 DispatchQueue.main.async calls in 2 different functions. 1 of them works, but the other one doesn't disable the button (the good thing is that you can click on the button and nothing happens). I am testing my code on my iPhone because the simulator does not run the SDK I am using properly.

All these functions look like this (this is the one at the end that does not work):

```
public func disableButton2(_ check: Bool) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async{
            self.button2.isEnabled = check
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used this and it was working fine

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + delayInSeconds) { [weak self] in
  guard let self = self else {
    return
  }
```

try this you will get the result.

Comment: The capture group `[weak self]` is pointless. `DispatchQueue` closures don't cause retain cycles.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but I do not understand what that does. I put what you told me to put in function, but the button is still enabled

Answer (score 0):

A kind of more accurate approach, in order to explain "why asyncAfter works instead of just async" would be that DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter would capture the thread in order to make the UI change to happend.
But most of the times could be because your are trying to update a view element within another view, say UICollectionView inside a UIViewController. In order to solve this you should call async method inside the method that makes this UI update